# Wrong number of Arguments with Lombok

Tags: java, builder, lombok

I am trying to use @SuperBuilder of Lombok, yet for some reason I am having the issue in compile time `Error:(14, 1) java: wrong number of type arguments; required 3`

That's my subclass;

```
@SuperBuilder
public class FetchFollowersOperation extends Operation<List<InstagramUserSummary>> {

    private String userName;

    public List<InstagramUserSummary> operate() {

        InstagramSearchUsernameResult userResult = null;
        try {
            userResult = instagram4j.sendRequest(new InstagramSearchUsernameRequest(this.userName));
            InstagramGetUserFollowersResult followers = instagram4j.sendRequest(new InstagramGetUserFollowersRequest(userResult.getUser().getPk()));
            return followers.getUsers();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the parent class is below;

```
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class Operation<T> {
    protected Instagram4j instagram4j;

    public abstract T operate();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is at line `public class FetchFollowersOperation extends Operation<List<InstagramUserSummary>>`. You must specify one type only i.e. T not it's inner generic type here i.e. replace it with `public class FetchFollowersOperation extends Operation<List>`.

This solves your problem. Though I went through lombok documentation and other details on what causes this issue, but didn't get any information on that.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Uh, that helps indeed but AFAIK, using raw types isn't the best. I wonder if I could somehow keep that type there...

Comment: Indeed! you should avoid raw types as much as possible. May be we can raise an issue at lombok so that they can fix it.

Comment: `@SuperBuilder` contributor here. `@SuperBuilder` heavily uses generics by itself, and further genetics on the annotated class makes the generics extremely complicated. So yes, you spotted a bug on a case I did not test. Please create an issue at Github.

Comment: With lombok 1.8.22, the problem seems to be still exist.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug, as @Jan Rieke mentioned. Reported via https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2262; it's been fixed and will be in the upcoming lombok release.

Comment: I would add that the version with the correction is the 1.8.16.